# Which is generally faster, an If branch or a 20 byte assignment?

Tags: c#, performance, optimization

If I am optimizing for performance, and I have the option of using a simple If statement that uses a boolean variable for it's condition,  or I have the option of transferring 20 bytes of data from one structure to a larger structure, which would generally be fastest?

I have no idea which one is faster, but if you think it's close enough where the branch predictor in the computer will come into play, would you say that if the boolean was random, the if branch would be slower, and if it was some sort of pattern most of the time, the if branch would be faster than the transferring of bytes?

Edit:

I understand this is context specific and such, and that if this was only executed once it would not matter. But please, just answer the question generally. If you had a **loop** of this, which would you expect to be faster? And obviously, the byte transfer would use structs that are both in main memory.

Comment: It's likely to be very context-sensitive... why don't you test this in your environment, in your real app, on the real hardware you'll be using? Do you even know if this bit of code is significant in your app?

Comment: First, don't worry about optimizing yet. Write the code and get it working. Then, *if and when* it doesn't perform well enough, profile to identify the *exact* bottleneck, and *then* you can try alternative methods of coding to eliminate that bottleneck with actual benchmark tests to determine the best solution.

Comment: Impossibile to say without context. Why not write the code and time it yourself?

Comment: emphasis on generally

Comment: The scenario you describe is not something really worth worrying about. A single `if()` will rarely have an effect on the execution of even a single function.

Comment: @xxbbcc Of course a single if would not matter. I am asking for the case of a loop and the case of optimizing for performance. Why is it so difficult to answer the question generally?

Comment: @BlazArt It's difficult because there's no "right" answer to your question. The answer depends on the data structure in question, whether the data is in memory close to the processor where it executes, etc. You're trying to optimize something so small that it's impossible to answer which is faster. Choosing a good algorithm will have far better savings. Other than that, implement both and test on as many computers as you can.

Comment: @xxbbcc Pretend it's your computer and make a prediction.

Comment: It can go either way. Copying 20 bytes from L1 or from main memory is a huge difference, the difference between a well-predicted branch versus a badly-predicted one is not as big but big enough. There isn't even a general case here, it can simply go either way.

Comment: @harold Yes, I am talking main memory transfer. No disk at all.

Comment: @BlazArt You're missing the point. There's no point in predicting because there are so many unknowns in the systems that you don't know which will be faster.

Comment: @BlazArt Is the boolean variable in cache? Are the source and target of the 20-byte-transfer? Do any of these values change during the loop? How does this impact caching behaviour? Too many unknowns. This is an unanswerable question.

Comment: You keep repeating the same question, and you're totally ignoring what we keep telling you. Perhaps if I SHOUT IT **LOUDLY**: **THERE IS NO GENERAL ANSWER TO THIS QUESTION.** There - does that help get you to actually notice what it says?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it depends.  A branch misprediction costs somewhere between 12 and 25 clock cycles, depending on the processor type.

A memory access from the L1 cache takes 2 or 3 cycles for 4 or 8 bytes.  But it has a very long tail of misery, this rapidly goes up for L2 and L3 and if the data isn't present in any of the caches then the processor can be stalled for *hundreds* of cycles waiting for the RAM.  The likelihood of it being present depends a great deal on memory access patterns.

So you just don't know.  You really *do* have to profile your code.